# How do i find sine(a) given 2 lines , each line described by 2 points?

Tags: java, java-2d, trigonometry

I have :

- Point2D line1_start , Point2d line1_end
- Point2D line1_start , Point2d line1_end

[image: lines]

Is there a formula to quickly do that?

Comment: Calculate the angle of each line separately, subtract the two angles, and take the sine of that.

Comment: "calc the angle of each line" - with respect to horizontal line?

Comment: omg, i know it now... DISTANCE BTW 2 points!

Comment: Hint: `Math.atan2(yEnd - yStart, xEnd - xStart)`